# Confusing behavior with Promise Callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Does anyone know how this works?

When I declare a Promise in a typescript angularjs class like this:

```js
constructor() {
var promise = customService.getObjects();

promise.then(
$scope.successCallback,
$scope.errorCallback);

$scope.successCallback = () => {}
$scope.errorCallback= () => {}
}
```

...these callbacks won't run when the promise resolves. When I declare them first and then run the promise, then the callbacks work fine. like this:

```js
constructor() {

$scope.successCallback = () => {}
$scope.errorCallback= () => {}

var promise = customService.getObjects();

promise.then(
$scope.successCallback,
$scope.errorCallback);

}
```

Is this some tricky javascript/typescript thing? 
It seems quite illogical to me.

Comment: In the first case you are passing to the promise a "reference x", and after you change this reference to "anonimous function", but the original reference was lost, and is undefined in the promise. You can declare a naming function instead and the reference is not lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're just passing 'undefined' into .then() in the first case. Do the functions need to be attached to $scope? Can you just make an anonymous function than are defined inside then()? Or you could make these functions themselves call the ones which are attached to $scope and not yet defined.

Comment: Well, I chose this above anonymous functions, because I reuse the same callbacks multiple times.

Comment: And connected them to $scope, because I'm handling scoped variables within them. (or is that unnecessary?)

Comment: I guess my question is: why the **** are they undefined when I define them just below. :)

Comment: The only reason you would attach a function to $scope is if it needed to be attached to an ng-click or something similar. If not you should just define it normally. You can access the variables as usual inside your callback, like $scope.var.

Comment: They're undefined because you passed variables to a function before initialising them. Therefore the reference that would've been passed didn't exist yet. Broadly speaking, Javascript and most other languages run from top to bottom.

Comment: I guess I'm used to C# where it doesn't matter if you define methods on the top or bottom of a class. Anyway, thanks!